# Laptop freezes when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I've already done the process of dual-booting on my Desktop, but for some reason I just keep encountering this issue on my laptop.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 on my HP Pavilion 15-cx0670nd using  [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/qNeJvujdB-0) .

It doesn't matter whether I choose for 'Try Ubuntu' or 'Install Ubuntu'. Everything will work for a couple of seconds, but then Ubuntu will freeze. Only my mouse is moving, but everything else is frozen. On another note, I've also noticed that my system won't reboot after checking the disk for defects.

I've tried creating the bootable USB with both the 'ISO' and 'DD' options, either will yield the same result.

Thanks in advance if some of you manage to fix my problem.

Comment: Make sure Fast Boot is disabled in Windows 10, likewise Fast Boot in BIOS. Also advisable to disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Also ensure that your flashdrive is formatted to FAT32.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Thinkpad X1 Extreme. Ubuntu installer freezes after 2 minutes. The mouse pointer is the only thing that's not freezed. It doesn't matter at which point you are in the setup process. I'm pretty sure it's time based

Comment: I'm not having this problem with Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 0):

Your Hp has Nvidia graphics card and you will need to enter nomodeset to the boot parameter to keep it from freezing until you can get the correct video driver for your card installed. [Here is a page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) that shows you how to do that.