# Problems with AMD drivers

Tags: login, amd-graphics, fglrx, nomodeset

I have the exact same problem as [this user](https://askubuntu.com/q/1107282/937798), but it only freezes under too heavy load, e.g. when I try to run the installer. I have a HP Pavilion 15-aw027no. After trying multiple USB's with no luck, I went on to DVD-RW's. This worked perfectly (almost), no freezing or crashing, but now whenever I try to install, I get this:

```
[Errno 5] input/output error
```

Tried a different DVD, same output. I've tried 4 different DVD's, all with no luck. I've tried to run Memtest86+ to test my RAM for errors, but it returned negative. I tried to run sudo fsck -cc /dev/sda6 to test the part of my SSD which I'll be installing Ubuntu onto for bad blocks. It returned almost 300 errors. I then tried to install in the same session, hoping it would avoid the bad blocks, but this didn't seem to be the problem. Errno 5. I tried HP diagnostics (F2 during boot) extensive system test, no errors, even though fsck returned so many errors. I tried again after all this, but I keep getting the same errno 5.

Also, I checked the MD5SUMS, SHA1SUMS and SHA256SUMS of the ISO I was using, and they all matched the ones on the website.

**UPDATE:**
Installation with bootable USB worked after adding `nomodeset` to the grub entry, but now `nomodeset` is present in the installed version of Ubuntu (the one on my internal drive). Whenever I try to remove `nomodeset` from the grub entry, Ubuntu becomes very unstable and freezes. The net time I reboot the system, I get [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSIFq.jpg)

I then booted from my bootable USB, executed `sudo fsck -cc /dev/sda6` and got [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atLQ1.jpg). The problem now is, I'm back to where I started. `nomodeset` is enabled again, and when I try to remove it again, same thing happens.

**UPDATE 2:**
Well, I didn't quite solve the problem, but I found the cause. I've been trying to install the `fglrx`-drivers, but I eventually found out that they aren't supported after ubuntu 14.04, so I went on and installed that. This time it didn't run in basic video mode, but it kept being unstable, and crashed all the time, so I tried to install `fglrx`, but no luck. I couldn't log in, I was stuck in a login-loop, where it would keep logging me out (this happened with the drivers downloaded form AMD's website too), so I pressed `ctrl + alt + f1` and logged in through the shell. By looking in some log files, and searching the web, I found out that my GPU (which is a Radeon R7 M340) isn't supported by `fglrx`, so I went on and uninstalled it, and after that, I was able to log in again. The open source drivers work OK, but if I try to play a youtube video, it will lag AF. I think I'll just avoid AMD cards from now on.

Comment: I thought AMD did not need nomodeset and AMD video driver was automatically installed. Have you updated UEFI from HP to see if that removes the firmware issue? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I did a firmware update a while ago, and I checked for new updates recently. By searching the web, I found that my GPU (Radeon R7 M340) isn't supported by either `Radeon`-driver, nor `amdgpu`-driver. I've tried ubuntu 18.10, which kept crashing and kernel panicking, 14.04.2 and 14.04.4, they both ran in basic video mode, without adding `nomodeset`, and now I'm on ubuntu 14.04.6, which is the only one so far running in 1080p and being quite stable (it still crashes and lags AF).

Comment: I have Acer notebook amd graphics R7 2GB chache. The Ubuntu 19.04 display flashes everytime. So,I have an Acer Aspire E 15 notebook with amd quad-core A10 and graphic R8 M445DX with 2GB dedicated VRAM. When I installed Ubuntu 19.04 the screen keeps flashing all the time. There is a problem with the amdgpu driver in Ubuntu 5.0 kernel.